# Pointer vector that preserves constness

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, boost, c++03

For a game I have a player class that holds references to e.g. all warehouses the player currently has. All actions are executed with GameCommands for lockstep-multiplayer.

Now an AI player could access the world and hence the player as read-only as to not accidentally modify anything causing an de-sync. So currently the player looks like this:

```
class Player{
  public:
    std::vector<Warehouse*>& getWarehouses(){return warehouses;}
    const std::vector<Warehouse*>& getWarehouses() const {return warehouses;}
};
```

So now the world-controller (the gamecommand) can modify the warehouses but the AI can't. Well the problem: It cannot modify the container but it could modify the elements contained which is an interface problem.

So I came across `boost::ptr_vector` which seems to solve this: Store pointers but all accessors return const references if the container is const and references if it isn't. This sounds ideal but does not work for my case: The player only holds references to buildings owned by the world. So it must not delete them.

Is there a zero-overhead way of getting a kind of const-view of the `std::vector` or tell the boost vector not to delete its items? It need to be fast as situations like this occur in different places throughout the code so it will be used very often. It is easy to do so it must have been done before.

Further restriction: C++03 only

Comment: Lol.. C++03 only?? Why??? Time to upgrade. In any case, can't you return a const pointer to const elements of the vector instead of a reference to the vector and a const reference (copy)??  Also, what about making one class a friend and have it use "private" accessor (non-const ref or ptr).. All other classes will only be able to access the "public" accessor (const ref or const ptr).

Comment: Example: https://ideone.com/G9Cr0M

Comment: We are using an apple cross-compiler. Thats why C++03. I really don't want to use `friend` or raw pointers due to encapsulation and security (vectors have assertions in debug mode for range checking etc)

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question, but it sounds to me you're solving this at the wrong level.  It sounds like you're trying to use language features to solve what should be application logic?

Comment: What about something like: https://ideone.com/mkurWF  It enables one function if the type passed in is `Meh` and all other classes get a copy instead..

Comment: @Matt The application currently does not modify the objects. However I do want to enforce this using language features. I think it is an interface bug to supply a `const std::vector<T*>&` function when a `const std::vector<const T*>&` is meant. Of course I could implement this with a copy of the vector but that means a performance penalty. @Brandon: This does not solve the problem that I want a const-view without a copy.

Comment: I understand. But if it's internal and not a framework then a decent set of comments is sufficient and will dave you time.  If it's a framework for others then yes

Comment: It's kind of both. Other people can write/change the AI or add new AIs where we cannot guarantee that someone does not accidentally/intentionally change the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a CloneAllocator `view_clone_allocator` that does exactly what is required: Copy copies only pointers and delete does nothing. So all one needs to do is store those containers as `boost::ptr_vector<T, boost::view_clone_allocator>` and that's it.

Reference: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/reference.html#id21